# Unhashable type 'dict' when trying to send an Elasticsearch geo query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get some geodata out of ES via the following snippet:

```
result = es.search(
    index="loc",
    body={
        {
            "filtered" : {
                "query" : {
                    "field" : { "text" : "restaurant" }
                },
                "filter" : {
                    "geo_distance" : {
                        "distance" : "12km",
                        "location" : {
                            "lat" : 40,
                            "lon" : -70
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

The query however doesn't succeed due to the following error:

```
"lon" : -70
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

The location field is correctly mapped to the geo_point type and the query is taken from the [official examples](https://www.elastic.co/blog/geo-location-and-search). Is there something wrong with the way I wrote the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are nesting a `dict` inside a `set`. Remove outer curly braces to resolve the issue. The error stems from the fact that sets, dicts can't contain unhashable collections like e.g. dict (thanks @Matthias).

```
body=
        {
            "filtered" : {
                "query" : {
                    "field" : { "text" : "restaurant" }
                },
                "filter" : {
                    "geo_distance" : {
                        "distance" : "12km",
                        "location" : {
                            "lat" : 40,
                            "lon" : -70
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: To be exact: The outer culy braces try to define a `set` and a `set` can't contain unhashable objects (like a `dict`).

Comment: ah, true, really forgot about the possibility to define a set using `{}`, thanks for that

Comment: I totally missed the outer curly braces. I also had an error with my ES setup so even without the set braces another error occured. Everything is fixed now. Thank you very much!